# How to generate integer sequence with macro only?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, preprocessor

As we know, c++ has `std::make_integer_sequence`, which can be used to generate integer sequence: `std::make_index_sequence<size_t, N>` => `(0, ..., N-1)`.

I hope to have a macro `MAKE_INTEGER_SEQUENCE(N)` and `MAKE_INTEGER_SEQUENCE(3)` will return `(0)(1)(2)`

How can we implement it with macro only? boost.preprocesser solution also welcome!

I have tried [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(macro, data, seq)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) with `macro(r, data, i, elem)` **`(i)`**

> This macro is a repetition construct.  If seq is (a)(b)(c), it expands to the sequence:
>   macro(r, data, 0, a) macro(r, data, 1, b) macro(r, data, 2, c)

But I have to provide a N-elems seq(like `(a)(b)(c)` above), which is pretty redundant for this feature.

The reason why I hope it to be a macro is I need such sequenses to generate multiple lines codes, like:

```
        ...... //primiary template above, specialize below, codes are from libcxx: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__tuple#L130
        template<>
        struct parity<0>
        {
            template<size_t Tp>
            struct pmake : repeat<typename make<Tp / 8>::type>
            {};
        };
        template<>
        struct parity<1>
        {
            template<size_t Tp>
            struct pmake : repeat<typename make<Tp / 8>::type, Tp - 1>
            {};
        };
        template<>
        struct parity<2>
        {
            template<size_t Tp>
            struct pmake : repeat<typename make<Tp / 8>::type, Tp - 2, Tp - 1>
            {};
        };
        template<>
        struct parity<3>
        {
            template<size_t Tp>
            struct pmake
                : repeat<typename make<Tp / 8>::type, Tp - 3, Tp - 2, Tp - 1>
            {};
        };
....
```

so, macro is the only choice here

Comment: Have you upgraded to C++17?

Comment: @TedLyngmo c++17/20 features are also welcome. But, iirc, the new features do nothing with macro.

Comment: Perhaps not, but ... is the macro solution (whatever it may be) the superior one?
What is the situation you are in to want this?

Comment: IMO, this is a superior one here. Because I have to much similar codes rely on sequences, what I paste above is just a small part of them.

Comment: Now I don't understand the question at all - I am just curious.

Comment: While I gave a PP answer, I'm not convinced that the question requires it. The code sample you show doesn't compile and uses the same name for the struct type, so it's hard to tell. If your goal is to produce something like `foo<0, 1, 2, ...>`, that can be done without macros.

Comment: OP: What's the purpose of this? The macro constraint feels strange.

Comment: *macro is the only choice here* --> Quite the opposite, this is some standard task for template, you just need some decent metaprogramming library, you can also write your own tools for those routines. [A simple solution with `boost::hana`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i8FjtxALRPedmBYo).

Comment: @liliscent Thanks, man! hana is pretty awesome! I never image meta template programming can do such thing. I'll dig it into later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with [`BOOST_PP_REPEAT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html) ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GAzZ8P)):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define TO_SEQ_ELEM(z, n, data) (n)
#define MAKE_INTEGER_SEQUENCE(n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, TO_SEQ_ELEM, )

MAKE_INTEGER_SEQUENCE(10) // (0) (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9)
```

Do take note that there is a repetition limit, `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_REPEAT`, which was 256 when I tested it, so this is the maximum possible value for `n`.